# Casting Integer Vectors in Java-ME

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am having problems casting an Integer Vector like shown below. Casting the String is ok, but i'm having problems with the Integer.

```
private Vector a = new Vector();
Record record = new Record();

record.setName((String) listName.elementAt(i));
record.setPrice((int) listPrice.elementAt(index));
a.addElement(record);
```

Below is the class **Record**

```
package goldenicon;


public class Record {
    String name;  
    int price;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Comment: so what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: What is the type returned by listPrice.elementAt(index)?

Comment: the error i am getting is, "Cannot cast from Object to int"

Comment: Why are you using a Vector over a List? Is there any reason you aren't using generics?

Comment: listName and listPrice is of type private Vector listName;private Vector listPrice;

Comment: Have you tried `(Integer) listPrice.elementAt(index)`?

Comment: i cant get Lists to work in the blackberry app development

Comment: with MadProgrammer example, i had to change int price to Integer price;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
record.setPrice((int) listPrice.elementAt(index));
```

You can't put primitive type inside Arraylist or Vectors. You have to use the wrapper classes for such operations, such as `Integer` rather than `int`, or `Double` rather than `double`.

Similarly, while retrieving the values from the Vector, you will get the object of Integer and not int.

So you will have to code something like this

```
record.setPrice(((Integer) listPrice.elementAt(index)).intValue());
```

Comment: the record.setPrice working. if i am retrieving an integer what do i have to write? i have a.elementAt(0); int z = ((Integer) Record.getPrice()).intValue(); and i am getting a red line in eclipse.

Comment: Why are you doing ((Integer) Record.getPrice()).intValue();  ? Record.getPrice() returns an int , so no need to typecast it.

Answer (score 3):

Java cannot cast an object into a primitive type. You have to invoke the object's method to perform this task. If you *know* that your element inherits from `Number`, you can just do

```
record.setPrice(((Number) listPrice.elementAt(index)).intValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast an object to a primitive.

You can do the following, instead:

```
    int z = (Integer) listPrice.elementAt(0);
```

And java autoboxing will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: java-me does not support autoboxing